# get keywords from a google instant search url

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the keywords that customers use to visit my website.
For that, I use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to get referer url and analyse it to extract keywords.

But during a google instant search, parameters are appended after a hash (#) and the keywords are no longer in the referer url. In this case, is it possible to get the keywords ?

I read that # in url never gets passed to the server. If it is true, is there an other method to get google keywords from instant search ?

For example:

```
google instant search: https://www.google.fr/webhp?source=search_app#safe=off&hl=fr&sclient=psy-ab&q=stackoverflow+php&oq=stackoverflow+php&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i30l3.800.19877.0.20202.26.16.8.2.2.0.106.1334.14j2.16.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.cQ13IWm1U0g&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.d2k&fp=d5d763d789c53203&biw=1600&bih=744

referer url: https://www.google.fr/webhp?source=search_app
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

i think you're approach is not possible. but what you want to achieve can be done by using [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/index.html) as shown here:

http://www.wordtracker.com/academy/monitor-with-google-analytics

its as simple as adding a Google Analytics(GA Code).

- [how to install GA](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en)

A Sample here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

although, if you want the keywords to be stored in your own DB, i doubt if you can do that.